# Try/Catch around multiple Unions inside SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a rather large SQL query that is performing a Union amongst several tables. This is used for an automation run that happens every hour. Occasionally, these tables will be rebuilt and when the query runs I end up getting an Invalid Object Name SQL exception because the table goes missing while it is being rebuilt.

As someone who is a complete novice with SQL my question is this

1. Can I have multiple Try/Catches inside a single query
2. If so how can I just ignore this one Union that is throwing the error and move on to the others?

Here is a sample of the query, including the Unions that I would like to surround with a try catch. My goal is to simply check if this Union works, if not catch the error and move on to the next Union

```
...

union
SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID
FROM [Store].[dbo].[lemon_table]
WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime

union
SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID
FROM [Store].[dbo].[apple_table]
WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime

union
SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID
FROM [Store].[dbo].[orange_table]
WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime

....
```

Would it really be as simple as this?

```
...

BEGIN TRY
union
SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID
FROM [Store].[dbo].[lemon_table]
WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
union
SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID
FROM [Store].[dbo].[apple_table]
WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
union
SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID
FROM [Store].[dbo].[orange_table]
WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

....
```

Also, would the SQL exception I am getting due to this even warrant being catched or is to "high" of an error? "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid object name"

Comment: That won't work. you can't put a `TRY...CATCH` in the middle of a statement. If you don't know if a table is going to exist or not, I suggest using dynamic SQL; however, this kind of design screams poor design choice.

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer is that when a table is altered, it does not go missing, and if you are actually dropping and recreating tables, you are probably doing something wrong. In any case, if you actually want the entire resulting dataset in a single piece, declare a temporary table/variable and insert each chunk into it separately, wrapped in its own `try`.

Comment: A SQL `SELECT` (even with `UNION`) is a single statement.  `TRY`/`CATCH` blocks go *between* statements, not *within* statements.

Comment: @GSerg that sounds like a good idea - do you have an example on how to do that?

Comment: @Cato Why into 3 **different** temporary tables? That just replicates the issue, but with Temporary Tables. The statement `SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM {Non Existant Table};` will not create a temporary table `#Temp`, and thus a latter statement `SELECT * FROM #Temp;` will error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think I may try just creating several different queries each with their own try/catch and then adding the results to an ArrayList. So where does the BEGIN TRY go? Right before SELECT?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temp table or a table variable and collect the data into it with separate try catch or if exists blocks
Then you can select back all the values as shown below

```
DECLARE @result TABLE 
       ( 
       project_id int NOT NULL, 

       ) 


    BEGIN TRY
      Insert into @Result (project_Id)
      SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID
      FROM [Store].[dbo].[lemon_table]
      WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH

    BEGIN TRY
      Insert into @Result (project_Id)
      SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID
      FROM [Store].[dbo].[apple_table]
      WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH

    BEGIN TRY
      Insert into @Result (project_Id)
      SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID
      FROM [Store].[dbo].[orange_table]
      WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH

    select * from @result
```

Comment: That produces duplicates. `union` removes duplicates from datasets being `union`ed.

Comment: @GSerg good point. A select distinct can eliminate the problem in this case. Or else check the duplicates during insertion to the table variable

Answer (score 1):

Using `Dynamic SQL` might not be the best way to do it, but could be one of the method:

Before jumping into the following query, assume you've already have a query to return all the existing fruits tables, and have a temp table or permanent table to store the result. Suppose we have 3 like you put in the example, then:

```
/* this only simulates above assumption
CREATE TABLE #AllExistingTables 
(
TableName VARCHAR(50),
[Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)
INSERT INTO #AllExistingTables
VALUES('Lemon'),('Apple'),('Orange')
*/

--Actual query:
DECLARE @Value_StartTime DATETIME = GETDATE()  --SET IT TO YOUR LOCAL VALUE
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Control INT 
DECLARE @Loop INT = 1

SELECT @Control = MAX(Id) FROM #AllExistingTables PRINT @Control

WHILE (@Loop <= @Control)
BEGIN
      SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' UNION SELECT [projectID] as ProjectID FROM ' + TableName + ' WHERE modifiedDateTime >= @StartTime'
      FROM #AllExistingTables
      WHERE Id = @Loop

      SET @Loop = @Loop + 1
END

SET @SQL = STUFF(@SQL,1,7,'')  --remove the 1st 'union' word

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, '@StartTime DateTime', @StartTime = @Value_StartTime
```

The query above have a potential issue is if you have a lot kinds of fruits, the `@SQL` will be truncated to 8000 Characters, which makes your dynamic query not complete.

Comment: Consider what happens when a table is removed after its name was written into `#AllExistingTables`, but before `sp_executesql` runs.

Comment: `TableName` has to be `sysname`, `@SQL` has to be `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: @GSerg, thank you for pointing out that timing issue in your 1st comment, could you explain the 2nd point? why `they has to be..`?

Comment: Has to be `sysname` because the name of a table can be up to 128 characters long and contain national characters unrepresentable in a `varchar`. `sysname` is a synonym for `nvarchar(128)` and has to be used if a table name needs to be stored. For the same reason `@sql` has to be `nvarchar`, so that it can contain the national characters from the table names. `sp_executesql` even [explicitly bans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) `varchar` constants.